# Is logrank test and its variations affected by the inequality of classes?

Tags: self-study, survival, unbalanced-classes, kaplan-meier, logrank-test

I am currently dealing with an home made exercise which compares the lifetime of patients who made use of a specific drug or not. For simplicity, I decided to remove censored data, but as replacement I wanted to study two scenario for which the imbalance of the two classes exists with different degrees.
What I did was computing the survival probability estimation through Kaplan Meier and therefore testing whether the two survival curves are comparable or not. I decided to use a Peto modified logrank test, but for the purpose of the question all the tests point to the same result, shown in the following plots:
[image]
[image]

So, the question is the following: by looking at the two plots, is it possible to state that logrank tests are affected by the inequality of classes? If so, what is the correct way to deal with? Should we opt for bootstrapping? The point is I cannot understand why, by looking at the pvalues returned, in the first case the two curves are considered not comparable whilst in the second, were hard inequality exists, yes.

Update: after EdM suggestion, I found that I simply got fooled by the plot. The test states that the two survival curves are different because the really difference happens on the first 10 days, which are plotted here:
[image]

All tests sustain the alternative hyphothesis, and therefore we can conclude that the two survival curves cannot be comparable given the differences in the early days of the analysis.

Comment: Both curves show p < 0.0001, so it's not clear what the problem is. Also, your 2 examples differ in the numbers of cases and events, which will affect p values. With enough cases even the smallest, practically insignificant, difference can show up as "statistically significant."

Comment: That's why to struggle to understand, especially for the first case for which the two curves seems graphically equal even if the pvalue says that the two curves are not comparable.

Comment: It's dangerous simply to trust the default limits of plots. For your first plot almost everything seems to be happening during the first  5 or 10 days, where you can't see any detail in a plot running from 0 to 200 days. Try re-plotting with different x-axis limits, say from 0 to 10 days. I suspect that you will then see a difference between the survival curves.

Comment: I tried. The major difference in the two curves arises from day 0 to 1. Depending on the type of test I choose, it may be more or less important to the computation of the pvalue, but in general everybody lead to the same result. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post a copy of that expanded plot, to help others who might come across this question? With the Peto modification there is much emphasis on those early times, while I recall (perhaps erroneously) that the usual log-rank test treats all event times equally. A comparison of the Peto adjustment against the usual log-rank test might also be informative here.

Comment: Done. No comparison between the tests was added since they all give a pvalue < 0.0001. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Note your two graphics present two different survival analyses. So which one are you dealing with?

By "classes" do you mean the "Drug" versus "No drug" group? And by "inequality [of classes]" do you mean that people on drug die slightly faster than people not on drug? Or do you mean there are a lot more people in the "No drug" class?

By imbalanced groups, I assure you (as it is asked again and again and again on stack exchange) that it really makes no difference.

The log rank test is a significance test for the hazard ratio, or rate ratio, comparing the incidence of events in the two groups. For instance, focusing on 50 day survival (in the second graphic), and assuming there's no censoring: you have a 7.5% survival rate for the drug group and a 12.2% survival in the no drug group. So the hazard ratio is approximately 4.7. If there were, say 100 times as many patients in the "drug" group, we would still expect a 7.5% survival rate and a hazard ratio of 4.7. All we would get is a tighter CI and a lower p-value reflecting greater precision due to increased sample size.

No test actually depends on a balanced sample. We encounter them so often because RANDOMIZED designs invoke the added benefit of randomization: that is approximately balancing the distribution of possible confounders at baseline, and eliminating their causal influence on the random assignment of "drug". In epidemiologic/observational analyses, you must control or match on confounding factors, and a bivariate analysis is useless no matter how large (or how balanced) your sample is.

Fun fact: 1:1 randomization is not necessary, and is not even optimal (depending on the analysis). A valid design can be obtained randomizing patients in a fashion of 3:1 or 20:1 without requiring any "correction".

Comment: The reality is I am dealing with both survival analyses. The classes are the groups yes, and by class inequality I refer to the size of the groups, for which I created two scenario: in the first plot you can see that I built the Drug class in a way it has around 3 times higher observation with a lifetime between 0 and 25 compared with the No drug class. In the second plot instead, I wanted to recreate a more extreme situation but for the No drug class in early lifetime values. All of this work was to understand why in the first case, despite the two survival curves are graphically

Comment: similar, the pvalue says that they are different. But your pointing on the survival rate percentage seems the key that now makes it clear to me: I must look at the number of events in proportion to the total number of people that are still alive up to that moment. This also explains now why the test does not depend on the size of the group.

Am I correct?

Comment: Still not clear, and unfortunately I don't think your line of reasoning here is correct. For a Cox model, the only thing that matters is the risk set, i.e. how many people are still at risk and at what time. So you can multiply all the event times by an arbitrary amount and make no difference. The "zoomed" graphic shows us that there are a lot of ties, so the power of the test reduces somewhat for handling ties. Otherwise, in both graphics p < 0.0001 so AFAIK the p-values are identical.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing intrinsically problematic about **imbalance** if both classes are large enough, but the Type I error rate of the logrank test does creep up if one class is too small in absolute numbers. [Pepe and Fleming (1987)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531492) showed this when both classes were small.  I have seen the same thing with genome-wide association studies where the Type I error rates for relatively rare genetic variants were elevated even though the *total* sample size was large. I was surprised (not having seen the Pepe & Fleming paper at the time), because the score test in a logistic model is *conservative* in the same setting and I had expected the logrank test to behave the same way.

Comment: I think this may be the case for the first scenario, but I cannot see this large difference between the classes. Drug class is around 3x the No Drugs one. I think this is a pretty common scenario, isn't it?

Comment: Since the article is not open, it might help to shed some light on what constitutes "too small". Scenario 2, while having the "stepped" look of typical small sample KM curves, still has a minimum of 229 in the risk set of the smallest group at day 1 and the survival curve drops from about 25% to about 12%, nevermind the hundreds who seem to die just around study entry. So what we have here are lots of ties.